# Transform Translate Chrome Bug Opacity Transition

Tags: css, google-chrome

so I have a div that I want centered in its container.

For that, I have the following CSS:

```
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}
```

But it seems that the `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` leads to a bug in opacity rendering of content within that inner div.

Notice here: **https://plnkr.co/edit/R1HzsNWTRuvmzdfnArO7?p=preview**

You will notice as the word in the `<span>` fades out, that (especially the buttons) the rest of the div gets a weird, faded out effect as well, even though they aren't being animated. When you get rid of `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` the bug no longer appears.

My question is, is there anything I can do here while maintaining the `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` or do I need to center it using `display:table` derviatives?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be surprised, but what you're actually looking for here is to set `text-align` on the parent element (in this case, `body`):

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Then you can remove all of the `.inner` positioning and translation code. However, to center the element vertically, you'll need to add `height: 50%` in `.inner`:

```
.inner {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

I've created an updated Plnkr showcasing this [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ijdkb3SdNplxmzYBv38C?p=preview).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually that doesn't work, because I'm trying to center this `inner` content within another div, vertically, not simply center it on the body horizontally. I need to either use this or `display:table` derivatives. I just simplified it for the purposes of the plunker.

Comment: You can still use `text-align: center` on the parent -- just set `.inner` to also have `height: 50%` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute centering on the `.inner` div and declare a height and  `position: relative;` to the parent div.

```
<html>
  <head>

    <style>
        .parent {
        height: 100%
        position: relative;
        }

        .inner{
          margin: auto;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
          border: 1px solid black;
          width: 300px;
          height: 200px;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="parent">
        <div class="inner">
            <h1>Hello Code</h1>
            <p>Hello Code Paragraph</p>

        </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

[Absolute Positioning](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to center `.inner` is to add `html,body { height: 100%; } body { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; }`